# how to deploy nuxt to heroku?

Tags: express, heroku, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt/express build I am trying to deploy to Heroku.

I followed nuxt documentation and have have set my heroku config like so:

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
heroku config:set HOST=0.0.0.0
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production
```

then I run `yarn run build` 
and I do `git push heroku master`

this is the error Heroku is returning:

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  8.3.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   5.6.0

       Resolving node version 8.3.0...
       Downloading and installing node 8.3.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 5.6.0 (replacing 5.3.0)...
       npm 5.6.0 installed

-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)

       > nuxt@2.1.0 postinstall /tmp/build_f6a907d9d4fe0608ddfe9868e86cb3da/node_modules/nuxt
       > opencollective || exit 0

       added 1142 packages in 32.448s
       Running heroku-postbuild

       > sms-funnel@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_f6a907d9d4fe0608ddfe9868e86cb3da
       > npm run build && npm start


       > sms-funnel@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_f6a907d9d4fe0608ddfe9868e86cb3da
       > nuxt build

       [18:55:29] vendor has been deprecated due to webpack4 optimization
       [18:55:29] Building project
       [18:55:29] Builder initialized
       [18:55:29] Nuxt files generated
Nuxt Fatal Error :(
       [18:55:30] TypeError: Cannot read property 'stylus' of undefined
       at Builder.extend (/tmp/build_f6a907d9d4fe0608ddfe9868e86cb3da/nuxt.config.js:44:58)
       at WebpackClientConfig.extendConfig (/tmp/build_f6a907d9d4fe0608ddfe9868e86cb3da/node_modules/nuxt/dist/nuxt.js:3144:56)
       at WebpackClientConfig.extendConfig (/tmp/build_f6a907d9d4fe0608ddfe9868e86cb3da/node_modules/nuxt/dist/nuxt.js:3286:26)
       at WebpackClientConfig.config (/tmp/build_f6a907d9d4fe0608ddfe9868e86cb3da/node_modules/nuxt/dist/nuxt.js:3182:33)
       at WebpackClientConfig.config (/tmp/build_f6a907d9d4fe0608ddfe9868e86cb3da/node_modules/nuxt/dist/nuxt.js:3325:26)
       at Builder.webpackBuild (/tmp/build_f6a907d9d4fe0608ddfe9868e86cb3da/node_modules/nuxt/dist/nuxt.js:3922:56)
       at Builder.build (/tmp/build_f6a907d9d4fe0608ddfe9868e86cb3da/node_modules/nuxt/dist/nuxt.js:3632:16)
       at <anonymous>
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sms-funnel@1.0.0 build: `nuxt build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sms-funnel@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.nHcrE/_logs/2018-10-08T18_55_30_342Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sms-funnel@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run build && npm start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sms-funnel@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.nHcrE/_logs/2018-10-08T18_55_30_355Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Inside my package.json under scripts I have:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build && npm start"
```

This is my first time deploying a nuxt app, I want it to run with the middleware and express, so I do not want it to be a static site. Do I need to specify that its a web app somewhere? I'm following the heroku instructions but shouldn't I be only deploying the `.dist` folder that is generated after I run `yarn run build`?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sms-funnel",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt build && nuxt start",
    "precommit": "npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build && npm start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "fastclick": "^1.0.6",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "gsap": "^2.0.2",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "nuxt": "latest",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.15",
    "splitting": "^1.0.5",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "tls": "^0.0.1",
    "twilio": "^3.19.2",
    "vue-keyboard": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.3.0", 
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "eslint": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do u have stylus and stylus loader in your packages.json ? If so what version?

Comment: Yes! I do. 
"stylus": "^0.54.5", "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",

Comment: are they in devdeps or deps?

Comment: @Aldarund they're in dependencies

Comment: @Aldarund I updated my answer with my package.json

Comment: Is it working locally with npm build & npm start? What for fs in package.json?

Comment: And try to disable cache. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#cache-behavior

Comment: have the same issue using Vuetify: says "Nuxt Fatal error, "dist" does not exists and should use "nuxt generate" where "npm start" was used it seems. Package.json has "build" set as nuxt-ts generate" so not  sure why npm start was run. Using Heroku too. any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `npm start` from `heroku-postbuild`.

Leave it like this `"heroku-postbuild": "nuxt build"`.

Because by default heroku does `npm start` once your app is pushed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried removing `npm start` and no luck.
I've also I tried `nuxt build` as well. What I currently have is `npm run build`. Keep in mind the app is working, they are just crashing 20-60times per 24 hour cycle for some reason.

Comment: @user3648969 if the app is running, then I don't think your question should be how to deploy to Heroku, because you did deployed it correctly. The real question is why is it crashing "20-60 times per 24 hour cycle for **some** reason".

Comment: @user3648969 if you're deploying your app to Heroku for free then it takes a bit to load and it goes offline if it hasn't been opened for X amount of time. Maybe this is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

After setting the environtment variables like you have, this is my "scripts" inside "package.json" file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  }
```

Remember you must create a Procfile file (with no extension) with this line:

```
web: npm run start
```

Answer (score 1):

My script in package.json look like this

[image]

Also, in config vars (Heroku)

[image]

Procfile: `web: npm start`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it like this

```html
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build && npm run generate"
  },
```

Adding the "&& npm run generate" at the end of the heroku-postbuild was the solution.